# How to notify all connected users?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm creating a chat using Meteor, and I want to create a button that makes plays a sound on all connected clients (to get peoples attention). What are ways to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple ideas:

1) a collection of 'Events'. Every time someone beeps, a new event is added. On the client, use Events.find().observe() and hook up an 'added' callback so that on new events cause a beep. The downside is that the database will keep growing as more events are added. You can limit this by only publishing the most recent 10 events to the clients.

2) a single document in the database with a 'last beeped' field. Clients store the last time they saw, and if the time in the database changes to something newer, fire a beep. The advantage here is that the database is a fixed size. Downside is the logic is slightly more complicated (I think. Maybe this is actually simpler)